# What should be the correct signature of the given method

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

This is the function I have:

```
FrmLoadingTimerID = setTimeout("UpdateKnl('"+ strType +"')",500);
```

Where the value of `strytype` is a string. In the `UpdateKnl` method switch statement is there therefore `strtype` should be followed and ended with ''. I want to send another parameter along with the function but not  getting the proper way to do so.

I have tried the following code:

```
FrmLoadingTimerID = setTimeout("UpdateKnl('"+ strType +"',abc)",500);
```

and

```
FrmLoadingTimerID = setTimeout("UpdateKnl('"+ strType +"',+"abc")",500);
```

In both way the value is not passed as an undefined error is throw if I try to assign the value of abc to other variable.

Comment: is strType defined in the scope. Can you  post the whole relevant code. i.e where it is defined

Comment: strtype is another variable value which is passed into the code it may be start or stop, and why you requires it's value? @SomeshMukherjee

Answer (score 2):

None of your snippets are correct, since `setTimeout` expects a function reference as first argument, not a string. You *can* pass a string, but just check what [MDN says about that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout):

> code in the alternate syntax is a string of code you want to execute after delay milliseconds (using this syntax is not recommended for the same reasons as using eval())

As we all know, `eval` is *evil*, and has but few valid use-cases. In this case, there's a better way to go about your business, so that's why the answer is:

```
FrmLoadingTimerID = setTimeout(function()
{
    //read as UpdateKnl(someVar, 'aString', 123, ['an','array'],{some:'object'});
    return UpdateKnl(strType, abc);//pass 2 variables
},500);
```

You might want to pay notice to the few conventions there are in terms of variable-names in JS: Variables *start with a lower-case* letter, and are *cammelCased*, functions start with a lowerCaseAndAreCammelCased, too, unless the function is a *constructor*, in which case it's to start with an *UpperCase* char.

Anyway, the code above should fix your problem, but be advised, though, that if any of the 2 variables change value in the 500ms before the timeout calls its callback function, the altered values will be used. To avoid this, use an [iife](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iife/info) to create a closure:

```
FrmLoadingTimerID = setTimeout((function(strType, abc)
{// assignes passed arguments to these vars //
    return function()
    {
        return UpdateKnl(strType, abc);//uses arguments of IIFE
    };
}(strType, abc)),500);//pass current values of these variables here
```

Read the tag wiki, it explains how this construction works, and why you should use it (it's similar to the infamous loop problem).

If, for some reason, you want to persist and maintain the madness of passing strings to `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout("UpdateKnl('" + strType + "', 'abc')",500);
```

This passes the string value of `strType` and a string constant `'abc'` to the function. If `abc` is a variable, that should be referenced when the timeout delay is ended:

```
setTimeout("UpdateKnl('" + strType + "', abc)",500);
```

By removing the quotes around `abc`, at the end of the timeout, the string behaves as if it were passed to `eval`: `eval("(UpdateKnl('" + strType + "', abc))")`, which is indeed *evil*. `abc` might have been reassigned by the time the delay ends... so I must urge you to refactor this code

Comment: This is inaccurate. `setTimeout()` will accept a string that it will then eval, although nowadays it's not really great practice and definitely not appropriate in this case.

Comment: i am modifying an old code and it was working correctly so i don"t think so the code can be wrong.

Comment: @millimoose: Yes, it's possible to pass a string, just as it is possible to parse JSON strings using `eval`... would you let that slide, too?

Comment: @user2644549: there's no need for quotes. if `strType` is a variable that holds a string, that _variable_ is referenced, not it's value. There's no _need_ to add quotes, like you don't need quotes when you use a variable anywhere else in your code...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem All I'm saying is that the statement "`setTimeout` expects a function reference as first argument, not a string" in your original version, notably the implied claim that "`setTimeout()` does *not* accept a string" was flat out wrong. I even said, right there in my comment, that it's a bad practice to use the string, so what exactly are you arguing about?

Comment: @millimoose: I'm not saying you were wrong, that's why I added the MDN quote, but I omitted `setTimout` accepting a string, because that's bad code, and I couldn't bring myself to posting an answer that left the OP with using strings instead of callbacks. I agree with your comment, saying it's innaccurate to say the first argument _has_ to be a function reference. My response comment was just to motivate my calling strings _wrong_. If somebody attempted to parse JSON with eval, would you give all regex's to sanitize the string, and _then_ suggest `JSON.parse`, or would you omit the regex's?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I'm still not sure what you're trying to convince me of, I didn't even -1 the answer for the inaccuracy. (Which would be counterproductive since the answer is useful regardless of it.) You're right to suggest using a lambda, and your motivation is correct, I just succumbed to a fit of OCD in pointing the thing that bothered me. In your hypothethical, I'd just point to `JSON.parse()` without saying anything like "you *can't* parse JSON with `eval()`". (As opposed to "you *shouldn't*".)

Comment: @millimoose: Ok, step back... we're both on the same page here. I agree with your first comment, and I know the OCD-feeling (If ever there someone earned the _"pedantic"_ badge, it would be me). I just wanted to clarify why I left out the string-option, by using an analogy (JSON vs eval non-sense). It made my answer less accurate, but I figured it would motivate the OP to avoid strings in this context, wherever possible, and perhaps learn more about JS. I'm not trying to convince you of anything, because that would be like preaching to the converted, from what I gather