# What's wrong with this code water boiling project

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing this for a class. The point is to show how to boil water in programming... idk it's weird but you can look at my code and see what's up. It has a purpose but I don't have time to explain. please don't make any big changes. I want it to run the way it is not how it should be done or whatever. I'm not the best with javascript so please don't judge as much.

---

### issue

it the first input works fine so no worries about that. It's my form that has issues.... what's supposed to happen is I type one of the variables in and it'll display what ever pour says. But when I go to submit it doesn't work whatsoever... just restarts the page! I give so far.... because I obviously don't know what's wrong :P something stupid probably. Thanks!

---

### code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Boiling Water
    </title>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor='#000000'>
    <center>
      <font color='#ffffff' size='8'><b>D.W.B.A</b>
      <br>
      Digital</font> <font color='#00ffff' size='8'>Water</font><font color='#ffffff'               size='8'> Boiling Association</font>
      <br>
      <font size='3' color='#ffffff'>Programmed in JavaScript</font>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p><font color='#ffffff' size='4'>Grab 1 of 56 Cups From the Kitchen Cabinet!</font></p>
      <font color='#ff0000' size='4'><p id="cup"><input type='button' value='Obtain Cup' onclick='cup()' /></p></font>
      <script>
        function cup() {
            var cabinet=56;
            var quantity=55;
            var obtain=cabinet-quantity;
            var cupP=document.getElementById("cup")
            cupP.innerHTML="You have Obtained " + obtain + " Cup";
        }
      </script>
      <script>
        function fill() {
            var x=document.getElementById("calculate").value;
            var optionzero=0;
            var optionone=25;
            var optiontwo=50;
            var optionthree=75;
            var optionfour=100;
            if (optionzero) {
                pour="Please Pour contents into your Cup";
            } else if (optionone) {
                pour="You have filled the Cup 1/4 of the way with water";
            } else if (optiontwo) {
                pour="You have filled the Cup 2/4 or 1/2 of the way with water";
            } else if (optionthree) {
                pour="You have filled the cup 3/4 of the way with water";
            } else if (optionfour) {
                pour="Your cup is filled (4/4 of the way) with water";
            }
            document.getElementById("fillup").innerHTML=pour;
       }
     </script>
     <br>
     <form type='input' >
       <font color='#ffffff' size='4'>Fill the Cup with Water per 25% out of 100% Ex) 25%, 75%, etc. </font>
       <br>
       <br>
       <input type='text' id='calculate'>
       <br>
     </form>
     <input type='submit' value='Calculate' onclick='fill()' />
     <br>
     <font color='#ffffff'><p id='fillup'>
     </p></font>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript code disappears after button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119773/javascript-code-disappears-after-button-click)

Comment: Please learn how to indent. I hope your instructor marks you down for it if it doesn't improve

Comment: ...and please don't use `<font>` tags.

Comment: Just a note - you set all the `optionzero` vars etc. Then you check wether it's true... And it is, since it is set. It's in a function, so It'll always be `pour="Please Pour contents into your Cup";`

Comment: Whoever your instructor is they should be sacked. Really <font> tags. They've been deprecated since 1999. Use style attributes or place the style in a stylesheet.

Comment: Not to mention the `<center>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

Simply try not submitting the form. You can either `return false;` from the `fill` function and change your inline handler to `onclick='return fill()'` or simply change the whole input for:

```
<button type='button' onclick='fill()'>Calculate</button>
```

Submitting the form is mostly useful when you want to send information to a server-side process which you don't need to do there.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is submitting to the current page.  You should probably move your `fill()` to `onsubmit` for the form.  Also, make sure that function returns `false`, or the form will still submit.